# android Twitter library integration

Tags: android, android-studio, twitter

I am using `Android Studio` and would like to integrate `Twitter`. I use `twitter4j-core-4.0.4` . use it as module. my dependencies is as below:

```
    dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.1.1'
    compile project(':twitter4j-core-4.0.4')
    compile project(':volley')
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:8.4.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:design:23.1.1'
    compile 'com.facebook.android:facebook-android-sdk:4.10.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:support-v13:23.1.1'
}
```

but when I run this project I got this error :

```
Error:Execution failed for task ':app:dexDebug'.
> com.android.ide.common.process.ProcessException:        
org.gradle.process.internal.ExecException: Process 'command 'C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_17\bin\java.exe'' finished with non-zero exit value 2
```

I searched but finally in vail. a problem with `Android Studio` or `Twitter` jar?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just need to change

```
defaultConfig {
        multiDexEnabled true
    }
```

Or just clean your project and try to run..

Comment: when i move my project to another machine then it works according to u but in my own machine it does not work. however thanks

Comment: glad to help you..accept my answer if it helps you :)